# sshtunnel python dynamic port forward

Tags: python, ssh

I want to use sshtunnel python module to do a dynamic ssh port forwarding like `ssh -N -D 9000 username@serverip` ssh command

is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO, have you tried?

Comment: What exactly should I try?